# Import urllib for module "request" error

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

```
import urllib request
import requests

goog_url = "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/GOOG?period1=1501517722&period2=1504196122&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=bU42Yaj88Bt"

def download_stock_data(csv_url):
response = ur.urlopen(csv_url)
csv = response.read()
csv_str = str(csv)
lines = csv_str.split("\\n")
dest_url = r'goog.csv'
fx = open(dest_url, "w")
for line in lines:
    fx.write(line + "\n")
fx.close()

download_stock_data(goog_url)
```

I'm trying to import a CSV file from the internet with this code. But I continue, despite my best efforts, to get a syntax error that says that it cannot find the request module of the urllib import.

```
File "/Users/Micmaster/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/firstProject.py", line 1
import urllib request
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've tried many different variations `"from urllib import request", "import urllib.request", "import urllib", "import urllib2.request"` and even changing versions of my interpreter on pycharm. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Your identation is all wrong. Please fix it.

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Comment: replace this `import urllib request` to `import urllib.request
`

Comment: The real question here is why you import `requests` and then proceed to ignore by far the easier of the two modules and start using `urllib` instead. I see nothing here that `requests` couldn't do.

Answer (score 0):

I will write about python2.

Why are you trying import request python or object from the urllib package, when this package doesn't have it.

And on the next line your import requests. So use requests.

And I don't know why you need urllib, but change `import urllib request` to `import urllib as ur`.

Comment: "I've tried many different variations("from urllib import request", "import urllib.request", "import urllib", "import urllib2.request")". You solution is already in the list of attempts from the OP... and apparently it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The `urllib.request` module is in Python 3 library; 
For Python 2 you'd use `urllib2`.

Comment: "I've tried many different variations("from urllib import request", "import urllib.request", "import urllib", "import urllib2.request")". Apparently they already used `urllib2` so I don't see how this answer differs from what the OP said doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib
from urllib import request
goog_url = "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/GOOG?period1=1501517722&period2=1504196122&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=bU42Yaj88Bt"

def download_stock_data(csv_url):
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(csv_url)
    csv = response.read()
    csv_str = str(csv)
    lines = csv_str.split("\\n")
    dest_url = r'goog.csv'
    fx = open(dest_url, "w")
    for line in lines:
        fx.write(line + "\n")
    fx.close()

download_stock_data(goog_url)
```

Your code should look like this. But it is still showing `HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized` you had taken the wrong URL.